# How can I darken the ECSlidingViewController view controller in the transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

The [documentation mentions adding shadows](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) to the controller being animated to show the slide menu. However, instead of a shadow I would like to make the animated view controller to be darker. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply created a masking view and presented/removed it on notifications from the slidingviewcontroller. Added some nice fade in and fade out action for effect :) Hope this helps

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
UIView *overLayView;
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *overLayView;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    overLayView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    overLayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(disableView) name:ECSlidingViewUnderLeftWillAppear object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enableView) name:ECSlidingViewTopWillReset object:nil];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:ECSlidingViewUnderLeftWillAppear object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:ECSlidingViewTopWillReset object:nil];
}

-(void) disableView {

    overLayView.alpha = 0;

    [self.view addSubview:overLayView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        overLayView.alpha += kViewHelperUIViewMaskAlpha;
    }];
}

-(void) enableView {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        overLayView.alpha -= kViewHelperUIViewMaskAlpha;

    } completion:^(BOOL fin){
        if(fin){
            [overLayView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Looks like those notifications were removed in recent versions of the control but I can recover them from github history and use them. Thanks.

Comment: 2 more things to know. 1. There's no notification posted in the current version(2) of ECSlidingViewController. You have to subclass [ECSlidingViewController completeTransition]; 2. I personally made a subclass of UIVIewController containing your implementation, for it looks cleaner.